# Error: Requested URL /conversations not found

Tags: python, api, chatbot, rasa

I am calling an RASA API from postman *http://localhost:5005/conversations*
but it is giving me an error.

I have created tracker store to store chat in SQL and I am using below command to run rasa.

`rasa run --cors "*" -m models --enable-api --log-file out.log  --endpoints endpoints.yml --auth-token thisismysecret --debug`

I dont know where I am getting wrong.

I am expecting following output.

````
```[

{

    "conversation_id": "string",
    "latest_event_time": 0,
    "latest_input_channel": "string",
    "intents": 

[],
"actions": 
[],
"minimum_action_confidence": 0,
"in_training_data": true,
"policies": 
[],
"n_user_messages": 0,
"flagged_messages": 
[],
"unflagged_messages": 

        []
    }

]```
````

**endpoints.yml**

````
```action_endpoint:
  url: "http://localhost:5055/webhook"

# Tracker store which is used to store the conversations.
# By default the conversations are stored in memory.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/tracker-stores/

tracker_store:
    type: SQL
    dialect: "mysql+pymysql"  # the dialect used to interact with the db
    url: "localhost"  # (optional) host of the sql db, e.g. "localhost"
    db: "db"  # path to your db
    username: "username" # username used for authentication
    password:  "password" # password used for authentication
    query: # optional dictionary to be added as a query string to the connection URL```
````

Answer (score 0):

That means that mot likely you did not correctly define the route/endpoint `/conversation`.

Comment: I have added endpoints.yml. in above code.what else is required you think?